# jQuery: Toggling a class with same specificity on a button when hovering and clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following styles:

```
button {
    background-color: blue;
}
.green {
    background-color: green;
}
.red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

And the following jQuery:

```
    $('button').click(function(e) {
        $(this).toggleClass('red');
    });
    $('button').hover(function(e) {
        console.log('hoverin');
        $(this).toggleClass('green');
    });
```

I want the following functionality for all buttons:

When a button is clicked, it should toggle between a red and blue background. When a button is being hovered over, it should toggle the green background. This is working in the code above only when the background is blue. I'm assuming it's because of css specificity.

If this is the case, and I want this functionality for all buttons, how can I toggle between red and green when they both have the same css specificity?

Link to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rtq2yoxx/

Comment: Why aren't you using the `:hover` and `:active` css pseudo selectors? It's essentially the same as toggling a class, but offers more specificity.

Comment: @PitaJ: Good question. Just because I'm getting familiar with jQuery event handlers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quick solution:  Move the `.green` style last:

```
button {
    background-color: blue;
}
.red {
    background-color: red;
}
.green {
    background-color: green;
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/k85sa7yc/)

You could also avoid the `hover()` method and use CSS3 hover instead:

```
button:hover {
    background-color: green;
}
```

[**Fiddle 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/k85sa7yc/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Set your `.green` rule color property to `!important`:

```
button {
    background-color: blue;
}
.green {
    background-color: green !important;
}
.red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I was told this is a bad thing to do.

Comment: everything can be bad if missused.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the css hover distinction:

```
button {
    background-color: blue;
}
button:hover {
    background-color: green;
}

.red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$('button').click(function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('red');
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s9sf7rtq/)